# Pointer Pointing to Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Lets say I have a variable:

```
char** code;
```

I then do:

```
*code[0] = "Lucas"
```

Is it valid to say that, `**code` holds an array of pointers (`*code` is the array which I am making strings) and that `*code[0]` will equal `"Lucas"` and that `*code[0][2]` will equal `'c'`?

Sorry if it seems elementary, I am getting very confused with double pointers!  Thanks in advance!

-Lucas Giancola

Comment: You need to reserve space using `malloc` before, e.g: `char **code = malloc(sizeof(*code) * n); ` and then `code[0] = "Lucas"` (without the `*`)

Comment: @AlterMann, You would probably get a warning/error for that because you'll be dropping the `const` from the string literal and will not have an array you can manipulate.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, "Lucas" is a string literal (in a read-only segment), true, but there is nothing wrong in the assignment.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: Not in C. String literals are of the type `char*` (actually `char[N]`), even though they're technically `const char[]`. This is an exception for mostly historical reasons, since C didn't always have `const`; it probably remains because a lot of existing code uses `char*` instead of `const char*`.

Answer (score 3):

Is it valid to say that, `**code` holds an array of pointers

No it is not. You have allocated space for a single pointer. You have told the compiler that that pointer will point at another pointer (that you have not created yet) that points to a character (that you have not created yet either)

```
*code[0] = "Lucas"
```

Is not valid code and  doesnt compile

```
prog.cpp:6:8: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
  *f[0] = "Lucas";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just have

```
char** code;
*code[0] = "Lucas";
```

you'll run into undefined behavior since you did not allocate any memory for `code`.

You'll need to use:

```
char** code = malloc(SOME_SIZE*sizeof(*code));
```

Even after that, using:

```
*code[0] = "Lucas";
```

is not good. There are couple of problems with that.

1. `code[0]` is a pointer. `*code[0]` is that pointer dereferenced. If you already have some string in `code[0]`, then, `*code[0]` will be first character of that string. The assignment is, therefore, wrong.
2. Also, `"Lucas"` is going to be in a read-only parts of the compiled code. You will need to make a copy of `"Lucas"` using `strdup` before you assign it to a variable that is of type `char *`.

You need something like:

```
 code[0] = strdup("Lucas");
```

Now you can use `code[0]` to access the whole string. You can use `*code[0]` to access the first character of that string. You can also use `code[0][0]` to access the first character of that string.

Comment: **Warning:** `strdup` is not standard C. It is a POSIX extension. You can easily write one yourself, though, via the use of `malloc`, `strlen` and `memcpy` --- just remember to name it differently (in case you *are* in a POSIX system).